# Possible root causes for fstream opening in write mode failing on Windows shared drive

Tags: c++, windows

Since a few days, I encounter instabilities when creating simple text files on a windows shared drive (Windows 10). The fstream file opening randomly fails.

- The file is obviously created in a folder for which I have W permission.
- The file.txt created by the bellow code is created by a unique application (no actual sharing of this file)
  The issue is seen on windows.
  Bellow is the code I run to reproduce the issue. It might run fine for a few hours then fails.

Does any one have ideas for a possible root cause (antivirus, known issue with windows shared drive ,...) and how to get more details on the reason why the file creation fails.

```
const std::string filename = "file.txt";
const int waitDuration_ms = 200;
const int maxAttempts = 10;
unsigned int loop = 0;
boost::random::mt19937 rng(0);
boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> waitBetweenLoops_ms(0, 1000);
while (true)
{
    std::cout << "Loop " << loop << std::endl;
    bool done = false;
    int attempt = 0;
    for (attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++)
    {
        fstream oFile("file.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
        if (!oFile.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "Attempt to write " + filename + " failed" << std::endl;
            Sleep(waitDuration_ms);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            oFile << "Hello World" << std::endl;
            oFile.close();
            done = true;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (!done)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create file: " + filename + " after " + std::to_string(attempt) + " attempts" << std::endl;
        FAIL();
    }
    const int waitNextLoop_ms = waitBetweenLoops_ms(rng);
    std::cout << "Wait next loop (ms): " << waitNextLoop_ms << std::endl;
    Sleep(waitNextLoop_ms);
    loop++;
}
```

Comment: Since it is a shared drive, does someone else have the file open?  Windows only allows one user at a time to write to a file.

Comment: No. This test code is running alone specifically to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Try adding an exclusion to your AV for the file/folder and see if it happens again.

Comment: @NathanOliver. Thx for the idea. We are waiting for our IT to add the exclusion. Any other idea?

Comment: You can use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from sysinternals to trace the file operations of your process. Look for `CreateFile` operations on `file.txt` - in case the opening of the file fails you also can see the exact error code there.

Comment: Also note that in general its a good idea to request both read and write access when opening files on the network, even if you only ever intend to write to the file. This allows the network redirector to use the cache manager (resulting in less network traffic) and also avoids a race condition that could result in writes to the file sometimes failing with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. (This is documented [in the CreateFileA documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#files) (near the end of the "Files" section))